# Linux script using a Hardware (True) Random number generator

Tags: random, rdrand

I'd like to use the built in hardware random number generator in my RPI3 for a project. Currently I'm only able to use /dev/hwrng to save binary dumps with

`dd if=/dev/hwrng of=data.bin bs=25 count=1`

What I need for my project is to read 200 bit long data chunks from the random source (/dev/hwrng) with a frequency of 1 reading/second and count the 1's in it and write the result as decimal into a text file with a timestamp, like this:

`datetime, value
11/20/2018 12:48:09, 105
11/20/2018 12:48:10, 103
11/20/2018 12:48:11, 97`

The decimal number should be always close to 100, since it is a random data source and the expected number of 1's and 0's should be the same.
Any help is appreciated....

I did come up wit a perl script that is close to what I wan't, so let me share it. I'm sure it could be done in a much cleaner way though...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
my @bitcounts = (
   0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 
   3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 
   3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 1, 2, 
   2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
   3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 
   5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
   2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 
   4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
   3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
   4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
   5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 
   5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 8
);

for (my $i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
system("dd if=/dev/hwrng of=temprnd.bin bs=25 count=1 status=none");
my $filename = 'temprnd.bin';
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "$!";
binmode $fh;
my $count = 0;
my $byte  = 0;
while ( read $fh, $byte, 1 ) {
   $count += $bitcounts[ord($byte)];
}
my $dt = DateTime->now;
print join ',', $dt->ymd, $dt->hms,"$count\n";
system("rm temprnd.bin");
sleep 1;
}
__END__
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to count how many bytes are greater than 127, this will probably give the exact same result ... and no need for fancy bitwise math on bash level.

Comment: if you want to go bitwise ... might be simpler to write a small python or c program to give you that (c would be much faster)

Comment: Thanks again for the update. I tried it and it gave me the expected results. However I believe that it is not exactly the same as counting every bit, because we loose the resolution of the data by staying on byte level. Statistically the mean of bytes larger that 127 in a sample pool of 200 bytes will be close to 100, but it will swing out more as we loose the bit level resolution. To stay on byte level and achieve the same as if we are counting on bit level, we need a look up array, like this:

Comment: How many to count per byte | for what decimals                 https://0bin.net/paste/Q2X-lP7YgM+Um7Sf#d4lEGvsp5fT58vDftSX1Tc0I2wYuzp23HropDE0fQf+

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following code

```
for ((n=0; n<200; ++n)); do echo $(date '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'), $(od -vAn -N1 -tu1 < /dev/hwrng); sleep 1; done
```

If you want to save it to a file, add simple redirect in the end
`> somefile`

Updating on the new request, try running the following code

```
for ((n=0; n<10; ++n)); do
    count=0
    for ((s=0; s<200; ++s)); do
        if (( $(od -vAn -N1 -tu1 < /dev/hwrng) > 127 )); then ((++count)); fi
    done
    echo $(date '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'), $count
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried it and it reads 1 byte at a time and converts it to decimal format (0-255). Instead of converting from binary to decimal, what I want is to read a 200 bit (25 byte) long chunk from the random source and count the 1's in it and print it with time stamp and repeat it every second. I'll also update the original post to make the question more clear.